# How to resolve a dependency's unique snapshot version into a variable in Maven?

Tags: maven

Consider a situation where I have a dependency `my-dep` of version `1.0-SNAPSHOT` inside my project. Is it possible to resolve into a property (or get in some other way) the value of its actual unique snapshot version as stored in the repository, i.e. in a form like `1.0-20200728.170522-51`? I'd like to use it in my application for technical summary purposes which would be very helpful in terms of the development process.

Comment: Something like this: https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/lock-snapshots-mojo.html ?

Comment: Yes I'm aware of this plugin, it's doing a very similar thing, but it results in saving a new version of pom.xml with snapshot versions resolved inside of it. But I'd like to get hold of the version during the build lifecycle so that resource filtering could use it.

Comment: Please explain more detail what the real problem is cause the given solution does exactly the thing...

Comment: @khmarbaise I would like to use the value of the actual resolved version of the dependency (that is `1.0-20200728.170522-51`, not `1.0-SNAPSHOT`) in resource filtering. Let's say I have a properties file in the resources directory that uses a variable like `${my-dep.actual.snapshot.version}`, so I want it to resolve as a result of resource filtering. Is there a way to set up such a property?

Comment: From my point of view it does not make sense to use a version in resource filtering apart form that in the generated artifacts there is the version already put into (`META-INF/maven/..`). which purpose does this version have?